# MySQL - Delete one row and re-order the others with the correct Sort ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which contains a bunch of rows and a **sort_order**.  I was wondering how I can do this so when I delete a row, say I delete the highlighted row with a sort_order of 7.  Then instead of 7 just being removed, I would need to change #8 to #7 .. #9 to #8 .. #10 to #9 .. and #11 to #10.

[image]

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Is it really necessary though? Even when you remove the said record, the sort order would still be maintained. (e.g ORDER BY sort_order). Recalculating the sort_order for each row after the delete operation with a large amounts of data would be inefficient.

Comment: -php tag, because it has nothing to do w/ it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you really need to change these values (`sort_order` will still work with gaps), you can

```
Delete From t
Where sort_order = 7
```

and then reduce the remaining entries by `1`:

```
Update t
Set sort_order = sort_order - 1
Where sort_order > 7
```

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer, and you weren't an ass about it like the other responders.  However, I would **very much** stress that you should wrap the delete and the update with BEGIN; and COMMIT; so that you maintain referential integrity. And use a proper table engine, like InnoDB.

Comment: What I was looking for. For others that were saying it's unnecessary: I give the user the ability to reorder things. If a user deletes for example 10 rows in the middle of the table, they're gonna find themselves clicking 10 times to reach the top.

Comment: @Spylot: In this case I would suggest to optimize your reorder algorithm instead. Exchange the sort_order with the next/previous sort_order that exists, this would save you from updating your whole table when deleting the record with sort_order=1.

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE sort_order = 7;
UPDATE table SET sort_order = sort_order - 1 WHERE sort_order > 7;
```

But, it is not necessary at all.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
Update tablename 
Set sort_order = sort_order - 1 
where sort_order > 7
```